# Collect data from a request with python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm using python, I would like to save certain parameters that are returned to me by an API call. At the moment I take the json that is returned by the request and loop it through the "for" with the keywords to save the parameters I want. For other calls I use the same system and it works without a problem, but here it gives me the error "TypeError: string indices must be integers" it doesn't fit the keywords. Even using integer indices gives me "[m][s]" which I don't know where it gets them.

the code:

```
def search(session, query_search):
    url = xxxxxxxxxx
    params = {
        "query": query_search,
    }
    response = session.get(url, params=params)
    return response.json()
```

in the main

```
query_search = "xxxxxxxxx"
results = search(session, query_search)
data_output=[]

for items_search_datadump in results:
        inside = items_search_datadump['posts']
        for items_data_datadump in inside:
            inside_data = items_data_datadump['data']
            for items_for_datadump in inside_data:
                title = items_for_datadump['title']
                url = items_for_datadump['url']
                content = items_for_datadump['content']

                listing = [title, url, content]
                data_output.append(listing)

 print (data_output)
```

the respons from the request:

```
{"posts": [{"type": "xxxxx", "data": {"id": "xxxxx", "meta": "xxxxxx", "title": "xxxx", "url": "xxxxxxxx", "user": null, "is_watched": xxxxxxx, "content": "xxxxxx"}, "additional": [], "owner": "xxxxxxx", "collection": "xxxxxxx"}, {"type": "xxxxx", "data": {"id": "xxxxx", "meta": "xxxxxx", "title": "xxxx", "url": "xxxxxxxx", "user": null, "is_watched": xxxxxxx, "content": "xxxxxx"}, "additional": [], "owner": "xxxxxxx", "collection": "xxxxxxx"},......
```

Comment: Are you using the *json* module to parse the response? What you've shown may be JSON but it's hard to tell as it's incomplete. What type of object is *results*? I suspect it's a string. Enrich your question by showing the API call

Comment: the error "TypeError: string indices must be integers" often means that you are trying to treat a list as if it was a dictionary

Comment: `items_search_datadump['posts']` is a dict. `for items_data_datadump in inside` will iterate over the _keys_ in the dict... the keys are strings. Then doing `items_data_datadump['data']` tries to treat the key string `items_data_datadump` as if it was a dict.  You probably want `for items_data_datadump in inside.values()` (and similar change everywhere else you try to iterate over dict values)

Comment: edited with the call of the api, in results i save the response.json() from the call. What i can't understand is because here with the same syntax (changing only the parameters) I get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for items_search_datadump in results:
    inside = items_search_datadump['posts']
```

When you iterate over a dictionary this way, you get its keys.

So in this loop, `items_search_datadump` will be a dict key, which is a string.

So then `items_search_datadump['posts']` is indexing a string with another string, causing the error.

Why are you iterating over the dict keys anyway?  You already know the specific items you want to extract (title, url, content), so I don't see how iterating is useful.

Try this:

```
results = search(session, query_search)
data_output=[]

for post in results['posts']:
    title = post['data']['title']
    url = post['data']['url']
    content = post['data']['content']

    listing = [title, url, content]
    data_output.append(listing)
```

Comment: it give me KeyError: 'title' (same for the other keys)

Comment: printing what i get from "for post in results['posts']" is this: [[{"id": "xxxxxxxx", "meta": xxxxxx, "title": "xxxxxxx", "url": "xxxxxxxxx", "user": xxxxxxxx, "is_watched": xxxxxxx, "content": "xxxxxxxx""}], [[{"id": "xxxxxxxx", "meta": xxxxxx,..................

Comment: @Webpe Oops, you're right.  I edited the code to add `['data']`

Comment: sorry, i don't see your edit (dunno if it is only for me).  i added another "for" for the [data] but in return i have the error "TypeError: string indices must be integers" like before.

Comment: @Webpe Okay, my edit is there now.  I must not have hit the "Save" button before.